# Overlapping of ArrayList in RecyclerView

Tags: android

I am trying to show a TextView inside a CardView by using a Recycler view.

and I used a check, to change the color and size of the text in recyclerView

that's my onBindViewHolder and condition to check ...

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull mAdapter.mHolder holder, int position) {
      MData d=list.get(position);

      holder.c.setChecked(d.isCheck());
      if(holder.c.isChecked())
      {
          holder.tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f44336"));
          holder.tv.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
          holder.tv.setTextSize(16);
      }
      holder.tv.setText(d.getShlok());
    }
```

The problem is: when I scroll, some randomly selected TextView got the color and size and it is changing randomly

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: use an else stt and set the properties back...

Comment: i am so frustrated by this ,that i forget to add the problem  ,

Comment: What @pembaTamang said will probably fix it. `RecyclerView`, well, recycles views. Uses old views and changes values on them. So if you're missing an `else` for every if, it'll reuse the old value that might be wrong, and certainly **won't be** the default value you had in your layout. If you understand what I mean.

Comment: Now that you updated the question, I'm 100% sure that what @pemba said will help you fix that. And my explanation should tell you **why** it occurred in the first place.

Comment: but when i use the same logic, with arrays not ArrayList , its perfectly fine , so is there any issue with ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

you have to change(undo) other textview color because previous recyclerview ViewHolder reusing

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull mAdapter.mHolder holder, int position) {
  MData d=list.get(position);

  holder.c.setChecked(d.isCheck());
  if(holder.c.isChecked())
  {
      holder.tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f44336"));
      holder.tv.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
      holder.tv.setTextSize(16);
  }else{
      holder.tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000"));
      holder.tv.setTypeface(null,Typeface.NORMAL);
      holder.tv.setTextSize(16);
  }   
   holder.tv.setText(d.getShlok());
}
```